# Unable To Play Youtube Video in Flutter,

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting below error while to implement YouTube video player in my flutter app.

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview.

how to solve this issue?

```
YoutubePlayerController controller = YoutubePlayerController(initialVideoId: youtubId);    
YoutubePlayer(
      controller: controller,
      showVideoProgressIndicator: false,
      progressIndicatorColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
    );
```

I am using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter)

Is there any other better way for playing youtube videos in flutter (apart from Webview)?

```
import 'package:cooking_genie/src/presentation/core/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class YoutubePlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return YoutubePlayerWidgetState();
  }
}

class YoutubePlayerWidgetState extends State<YoutubePlayerWidget> {
  //late YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayer(
      controller: YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: 'zn2GwbPG-tc', //Add videoID.
        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
          hideControls: false,
          controlsVisibleAtStart: true,
          autoPlay: false,
          mute: false,
        ),
      ),
      showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
      progressIndicatorColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}

///
class Controls extends StatelessWidget {
  ///
  const Controls();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          _space,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _space => const SizedBox(height: 10);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to play on web?

Comment: NO , I am using the package i have mentioned in the question...May be the package using Webview internally.

Comment: where you are testing this app , emulator, device or web browser/chrome?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Testing on Emulator

Comment: can you share the full widget?

Answer (score 1):

check this widget. and make sure to change `minSdkVersion 22` on andorid>app>build.gradle. package require >=17 for android.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class YTplayerCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  YTplayerCheck({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YTplayerCheckState createState() => _YTplayerCheckState();
}

class _YTplayerCheckState extends State<YTplayerCheck> {
  YoutubePlayerController controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: 'iLnmTe5Q2Qw',
    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
      autoPlay: true,
      mute: true,
    ),
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: false,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```